# How to process result sets for implicit cursors in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am looking for some help to write a data transition SQL script (or perhaps PL/SQL script?) based on the following rules below.

```
For each person...
1) If all three tasks are 'done', do nothing
2) If 'wake up' task is 'awaiting', do nothing
3) Else, INSERT a new record for person WHERE item = 'go to work' 
and status = 'awaiting'

tasks table:
id     person     item          status
1      john       wake up       done
2      john       brush teeth   done
3      john       get dressed   done
4      amy        wake up       done
5      amy        brush teeth   done
6      amy        get dressed   done
7      frank      wake up       awaiting
8      sue        wake up       done
9      sue        brush teeth   started   
10     andy       wake up       done
11     andy       brush teeth   started
12     andy       get dressed   started   
...
...
...
```

While I have some SQL experience, I have just started to learn PL/SQL. I believe that PL/SQL may be needed here to loop through each person, examine the persons records, and apply the IF THEN logic.

Here is what I have so far:

```
BEGIN
    FOR task IN (SELECT DISTINCT person
        FROM tasks)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Processing... ' || task.person || ', ' || task.item || ', ' || task.status);
        -- This is where I am having trouble. 
        -- How can I examine all rows for each candidate 
        -- at once when each row is returned only one at a time?
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Do you have a sequence configured for the id column to insert values incrementally or are you inserting the id value manually?

Comment: Yes, there is a sequence configured.

Comment: Do you also have a BEFORE INSERT trigger to get the new id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tasks
  SELECT MYSEQ.NEXTVAL,Person,item,status
  FROM
  (
     SELECT person,
           'go to work' AS item
           'AWAITING' as status
     FROM tasks
     GROUP BY person
    HAVING COUNT(DECODE(status,'AWAITING',1)) = 0 AND COUNT(*) <> 3
  ) MYVIEW
```

Hope a query like this, should help you?

Still, for a PL/SQL Solution:

```
BEGIN
    FOR task IN (SELECT DISTINCT person
        FROM tasks)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Processing... ' || task.person || ', ' || task.item || ', ' || task.status);
        INSERT INTO tasks
            SELECT 
             MYSEQ.NEXTVAL,
             task.person,
             'go to work',
             'AWAITING'
            FROM dual
            WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 'x' FROM tasks t
             WHERE t.person = task.person AND t.status = 'AWAITING');


         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT) || ' rows inserted.');
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following SQL query to insert the new rows, as required. The same logic can be built into a loop using PL/SQL, but the set-based SQL processing would be much faster than looping and processing record by record.

The following query assumes that you have a BEFORE INSERT trigger that gets the next value from the sequence to update the id column.

```
INSERT INTO tasks (person, item, status)
SELECT
    person, 'go to work', 'awaiting'
FROM persons
WHERE (task = 'wake up' AND status <> 'awaiting')
OR person in
(
    SELECT
        person
    FROM tasks
    WHERE status = 'done'
    GROUP BY person
    HAVING count(*) <> 3
) persons_done;
```

Otherwise, you can manually get the next value from the sequence, as:

```
INSERT INTO tasks (id, person, item, status)
SELECT
    my_sequence.nextVal, person, 'go to work', 'awaiting' --Replace my_sequence with the name of the sequence in your database
FROM persons
WHERE (task = 'wake up' AND status <> 'awaiting')
OR person in
(
    SELECT
        person
    FROM tasks
    WHERE status = 'done'
    GROUP BY person
    HAVING count(*) <> 3
) persons_done;
```

**Reference**:

[Thanks for the question regarding "Cursors or queries?", version 9.2.0 on AskTom Oracle](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:73891904732164)